# When re-sourcing vimrc, the highlight commands following the colorscheme choice are lost

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, cursorline

Given this `~/.vimrc`

```
syntax on
colo pablo
set cul
hi CursorLine cterm=bold ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE gui=bold guibg=NONE guifg=NONE
hi String ctermfg=red
```

Do the following:

- open a file, possibly containing some string (so a double quoted sting in Vim or on C++, for instance);
- observerve that, expectedly,

  - the coloring of the strings is `red`, not the one dictated by `pablo`
  - the current line is highlighted with bold text rather than with the true underline dictated by `pablo`
- run `:mksession`
- close the file
- reopen the session with `vim -S Session.vim`
- observe that, unexpectedly to me, the file opens just like the 4th and 5th line of the `~/.vimrc` were not there.

In the following screencast you can see the effect on the colors of the strings (not on the underline, unfortunately, because of how asciinema works, I guess).

[image: asciicast]

Comment: @JakeGrossman, I see it is related, but maybe a more specific answer to how the colorscheme and the vimrc interact with `vim -S Session.vim` would be better.

Comment: @Enrico so what does `:verbose :hi String` return?

Comment: I’m not convinced it’s all that different, and the solution is the same: put the highlight commands in an autocommand.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, `String         xxx ctermfg=9` when opening _without_ `-S`, `String         xxx links to Constant` when opening _with_ `-S`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, could you write an answer, then? I've found that the linked answer works, in some way, but having _your_ opinion would be better. Why? Putting the 4th and 5th lines of my example vimrc in `autocmd ColorScheme *` fixes the thing when I open with `-S`, but breaks it when I don't (it kind of inverts the behavior); so I tried putting those two lines _both_ inside and outside the autocommand, and it works. But it looks a lot like the wrong way to me. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn’t be necessary. Have you peeked in the session for to see if it contains anything about syntax, color scheme, or highlight? Check sessionoptions too

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, putting the two `hi` commands only in the `autocmd` makes them not executed upon startup of Vim (but they are executed if I open via `vim -S Session.vim`), so there's no session file I can peek in.

Comment: Yes there is: `Session.vim`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, maybe I wasn't clear. I'm saying that if I have the two `hi` command _only_ in the `autocmd ColorScheme *`, and I open a file with `vim that_file`, I see that the two `hi` command have no effect. And this is before I even think of creating a session.

Comment: The autocmd needs to be defined before you call colorscheme

Comment: Ok, that was it. And so I have to put all `hi` commands that happen to be in vimrc into that autocmd, before I call `colo whatever`, right?